# Finding matching weight for two differing types of cat food

Tags: calculus, linear-programming

Attempting to figure out how much cat food to give my cat I came across a problem which I am unsure of any way other than iteration to solve.

The problem I have is that I have been advised to feed my cat there regular food and a special diet for tooth cleaning.  The vet advised to feed half and half but the two types of food have different calorie levels.  The regular food advises for me to feed 50g a day and the dental advises 65g.  As such I could opt for the easy solution of splitting each in half and using that, indeed this is what I am doing.

However my question is, is there a means of finding the weight that is the same for both foods?

I know the answer to be approximately 28.26, which I arrived at through an iterative process but would love to know if there is a better way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want your cat to get $C$ calories a day, you know 50g of the regular food  will provide this, as will 65g of the special food.

So regular food provides $\dfrac{C}{50}$ calories per gram, and special $\dfrac{C}{65}$ calories per gram.

You want an equal weight $W$ of each food to now provide the same calories. So

$W * \dfrac{C}{50} + W * \dfrac{C}{65} = C$

This gives us

$W * (\dfrac{1}{50} + \dfrac{1}{65}) = 1$

$W * (\dfrac{23}{650}) = 1$

$ W = \dfrac{650}{23} = 28.26087...$

Comment: Thank you, its obvious now I see it :)